# unable to web scrape all the data not fetching all <td> values

Tags: python, web-scraping

I Am trying to scrape the html table for this site but unable to fetch chhange(24h) column

```
from requests import get
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

content = urlopen("https://coinmarketcap.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
rows = soup.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    row.find('td', {'data-timespan': '24h'}).text)
```

unable to fetch the  tag for change(24h) while we i try to debug **rows** it contains that tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source page reveals, they have an extra anchor tag closed, just near the element you require. So, bsoup is not able to get it. Probably, it was intentional so as to introduce a layer of complexity, for people scrapping that out. :P Or may be unintentional.

[image]

See the first and last line of marked text in the image, two  tags, causing chaos for the bSoup's DOM parser.

So solution would be, to find those element directly, instead of traversing children of each , cause that is where that culprit closing tag is present.

```
from requests import get
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


content = urlopen("https://coinmarketcap.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

rows = soup.find_all('td', {'data-timespan': '24h'})

for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

This gives, what you want.
Another way would be to find the required element via RegExp pattern matcher, inside the loop, from "row" (refering to your code).

Comment: rows = soup.find_all('tr') is this ryt to find all tr tag ?

Comment: Yes it is.
But when you are iterating over each of the "tr" element, innerText of it is treated as a  DOM Tree. This tree is invalid due to extra </a> tag, which is causing problem for DOM Parser, to find your required element. In ideas case, it should work. But, not here!

Comment: If it was helpful, please be generous to rate the comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

hey you can use a package which i made...https://github.com/sarthaknegi/easy_scrape

simple

```
from easy_scrape.scrape_table import scrape_table

scrape_obj =scrape_table(#give your path to the chrome driver)
data = scrape_obj.table(url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/' , class_name='dataTable')
```

Note : Don't forget

> pip install selenium & 
>   pip install easy_scrape

Note: Also, please edit the result as per need

PS : please check their robots.txt